# pdf opening issue in emacs terminal

Tags: pdf

I am a new user of emacs. I have installed emacs 27.1 in my Ubuntu 22.04. I can successfully open my ms.tex file in emacs (terminal). After that, I press the `C-c C-c` command and then I type my file name as ms.tex. It successfully creates the  ms.pdf file in my directory. Then I press `C-c C-c` and then I type `\doc-view ms.pdf RET`. It does not show the actual pdf. It shows an encoded version of ms.pdf file. I also typed `M-x doc-view-minor-mode RET` on emacs. After that, I pressed `C-c C-c` then an error message appears, the message says that `unable to render, view extracted text instead?. (y or n)`. After typing `y RET` it does not show the right pdf and it shows an error message which says `Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil`. I can open my ms.pdf file using `evince ms.pdf` externally but I can not open it in emacs. I searched my problem on google and based on some answers I have tried to modify my `C-x C-f ~/.emacs.d/init.el` file but it has not worked. After pressing `M-x package-install` after that I type pdf-tools it does not show anything. Ghostscript and xpdf are already in the newest version.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: you've showed us what you've tried to do, but to elaborate on @drew's question, what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to open pdf in emacs, meaning to say, after pressing the C-x C-f command and after pressing the C-c C-c command, I want to see my pdf file within emacs (not externally).  After running pdflatex command the pdf should be updated automatically. Hope I have answered.

Comment: If Emacs is running inside of a terminal, then you cannot do that. Can you run the Emacs gui instead?

Comment: Yes. If I run emacs gui, I can open the pdf with \doc-view. I want to do the same thing using emacs terminal.